# Calling a jQuery function on an HTML element returned from AngularJS's ng-view directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using angularJS and the $route service to load a partial view file like so.

```
<ng-view onload="onViewLoad()">
</ng-view>
```

works fine.

My Problem is trying to call a jQuery function on an html element that is returned specifically trying to call the jQuery bigtext() function on a header class from the partial file. I have tried

```
        $scope.onViewLoad = function(data){
            $(.bigTitle).bigtext({
                maxfontsize: 40 // default is 528 (in px)
            };
        });
```

and many similar things, but my problem is that I can not figure out how to select an element by class or id from the partial view. Can anyone tell me or lead me in the right direction to what the reason I can not access elements from the partial view. If a more robust sample of any of the code will help let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything like this needs to be done in a directive. This assures you the element exists when code fires and is simple to call the plugin directly on the element ... no need to worry about classes or ID's

HTML

```
<h3 big-text>My Header</h3>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('bigText', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // "A" for attribute
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            // elem is jQ object
            elem.bigtext({
                maxfontsize: 40 // default is 528 (in px)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Note that `elem` is a jQuery object inside `link` when jQuery.js is included in page before angular.js loads, otherwise it is a jQlite object with many (but not all) jQuery methods included

Comment: <h3 big-text>My Header</h3> how does the big-text in this h3 tag if you don't mind?